# Tres select dependientes de otro select ejemplo pais->departamento->ciudad

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estoy intentando realizar un select dinámico, con este código funciona perfecto, pero solo con dos select, si quiero añadir uno nuevo dependiente del segundo que se lleno al elegir opciones del primero ya no funciona, alguien me puede colaborar como lo hago, es como si no cargara los datos para enviar por ajax del segundo select.

```
<div class="col-md-4 mb-4 md-form">
                    <label for="tipopqr">Tipo PQR</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="tipopqr" id="lista1" onkeypress="return tabular(event,this)" required>
                        <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                        <?php while ($filat = mysqli_fetch_array($tipopqr)) : ?>
                            <option value="<?= $filat['pqr_tip_id']; ?>"> <?= utf8_encode($filat['pqr_tip_nom']); ?></option>
                        <?php endwhile ?>
                    </select>
                </div>

<div class="col-md-4 mb-4 md-form" id="select2lista">


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        recargarLista();

        $('#lista1').change(function(){
            recargarLista();
        });
    })
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function recargarLista(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"funcionespqr/select_subtipo.php",
            data:"tipo=" + $('#lista1').val(),
            success:function(r){
                $('#select2lista').html(r);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Solo veo el codigo del primer select.  Deberias de agregar el codigo del segundo donde tienes problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se podría hacer de la siguiente manera:

- Asignar id a cada elemento select

> ```
> <select id="pais"></select>
> <select id="depto"></select>
> <select id="ciudad"></select>
> ```

- Agregar  funciones onchange para los 2 select dependientes (depto,ciudad)

> ```
> <select id='pais' onchange="pais()"></select>
> <select id='depto' onchange="depto()"></select>
> <select id='ciudad'></select>
> ```

- Crear las funciones onchange dependientes y capturar los id del pais y el departamento

> ```
> function pais(){
> var ciudad = $("#pais").val();
> //Enviar pais por ajax y recuperar los datos para llenar el select departamentos
> }
> function depto(){
> var ciudad = $("#ciudad").val();
> //Enviar ciudad por ajax y recuperar los datos para llenar el select ciudad
> }
> ```

Estas funciones identifican los cambios de valor que se hagan en cada uno de los select, ya queda a tu creatividad mejorar esto a tu medida.