# Seccionar opciones con php

Tags: php, mysql

Estamos en un proyecto de registro de mascotas, queremos que nos ayuden en lo siguiente, tenemos un combo de especies cuyos datos lo recogemos de la base de datos, las especies son Perros y Gatos, queremos que al momento de dar click en perros se filtre la raza de los perros y al dar click en gatos de filtre la raza de los gatos..

Combo especies

```
             <label for="raza-mascota">Especie</label>
                  <select
                    data-toggle="tooltip"
                    data-placement="bottom"
                    title="Este campo es obligatorio"
                    class="form-control"
                    id="especieMascotaRegistra"
                    onchange="addCleseEspeRegistra()"
                    name="especie"
                  >
                    <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
                    <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT idespecie, descripcion FROM especie";
                    $query = $conexion->query($sql);
                    while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                        echo "<option value='" .
                            $valores['idespecie'] .
                            "'>" .
                            $valores['descripcion'] .
                            "</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                  </select>
```

Combo razas

```
          <label for="raza-mascota">Raza</label>
                  <select
                    data-toggle="tooltip"
                    data-placement="bottom"
                    title="Este campo es obligatorio"
                    class="form-control"
                    id="razaMascotaRegistra"
                    onchange="addCleseRazaRegistra (), 
                              remCleseRazaRegistra()"
                    disabled
                    name="raza"
                  >
                    <option value="0" >Selecciona</option>
                    <!-- <option value="4">Otros</option> -->
                    <?php
                    $sql =
                        "SELECT idespecie, descripcion FROM raza;
                    $query = $conexion->query($sql);
                    while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                        echo "<option value='" .
                            $valores['idespecie'] .
                            "'>" .
                            $valores['descripcion'] .
                            "</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                  </select>
```

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: Lo que vez, no sé cómo filtrar, o no sé cómo hacerlo, lo que explico en la publicación

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con Ajax.

Comment: Me puedes explicar como......

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/266586/tres-select-dependientes-de-otro-select-ejemplo-pais-departamento-ciudad

Comment: En san Google hay muchísimos ejemplos de cómo usar AJAX, si buscas `$.ajax` de jQuery es un método más fácil de utilizar, además esta pregunta creo que ya te la había contestado, sólo que utilicé arreglos con razas estáticas como ejemplo, tú lo tendrías que hacer dinámico trayendo tus datos de la BD.

Comment: Estoy utilizando lo que me explicaste es problema surge cuando utilizo php, pero igual estoy revisando..ñ